# Start mod_perl handler from another perl module

Tags: perl, mod-perl, mod-perl2

How can I start a mod_perl handler (called MyCacheHandler.pm) directly from another perl module (called MyModule.pm). Because currently I'm starting the handler via a web browser, but it would be a little bit easier to call it with MyModule.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to have it (`MyCacheHandler`) running in the background, and it won't produce any visible (to a browser) output? (Just side effects).

If that's correct, why is it even implemented as a `mod_perl` handler. Just implement it as a script and run it from `cron`, or as a `daemon` of some kind.

You could still *control* `MyCacheHandler` from `MyModule` (say via IPC).

Comment: Well, I can't use MyCacheHandler as cron, because I only need it if MyModule was used. So the user starts MyModule I need MyCacheHandler, so I want to call something like PerlModules::MyChacheHandler::handler() in MyModule. Will it work?

Comment: It depends what `MyCacheHandler` *does*. In your previous question you had it set three different cache values, sleeping between calls to `set`. If you call that function from inside your `MyModule` handler, then it will 'block' the rest of the code in `MyModule` from running. You need some way to run it in the background.

Comment: Ok. I understand the problem. So is it possible to use Apache2::SubProcess to start a new sub process which start the MyCacheHandler?

Comment: I've personally never used `Apache2::SubProcess` but it looks like it would work. Give it a go, and if you have trouble, edit your question to get some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Do some refactoring. Split `MyCacheHandler.pm` into two modules: one which is doing the hard work and does not depend on `mod_perl` anymore (that is, no more handling with `$r`), so it's callable from other modules. The other would be a now thin `mod_perl` handler calling the first module.

Or leave it as is, and just use `LWP::UserAgent` to access `MyCacheHandler` from `MyModule`.

Comment: He doesn't mention it in the post, but @atticus3000 wants the code in `MyCacheHandler` to run asynchronously with respect to `MyModule`. No amount of refactoring will fix this.